# Apache config files order

Tags: apache-virtualhost

I have an application (OTRS) and it is using Apache 2.4 as web server. Now I can see the main configuration file `httpd.conf` but as well a file that was deployed with the OTRS rpm `/etc/httpd/conf.d/zzz_otrs.conf`

From Apache documentation [Apache 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/invoking.html)

```
The first thing that httpd does when it is invoked is to locate and read the configuration file httpd.conf.
```

So my questions are:
 - is Apache "building" a configuration file from the httpd.conf file and all the includes like the OTRS file from above, if yes can one somehow overwrite the other ?

- does it matter in which file I perform changes ?

many thanks !

Answer (score 4):

If you look in your `httpd.conf`, search for `Include` and/or `IncludeOptional`. Your (well, your distro's) `httpd.conf` is what instructs Apache to load `conf.d`; it thus also determines when its loaded vs. the directives in `httpd.conf`.

What happens if you have two of the same directives in the config is complicated. It depends, at least, on the directive; some (e.g., `Require`) add to the previous ones. Some modify or overwrite them, depending on exact syntax used (e.g., `Options`). Similarly, global config and per-vhost config (and per-directory and per-location and...) combine in interesting ways. You have to check the Apache docs for details.

Comment: yes in fact I can see the following line # Load config files in the `"/etc/httpd/conf.d" directory, if any.
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf`
Regarding the Apache docs. Are you referring to [Directive Quick Reference](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/quickreference.html)